# How to Update table row using regex

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with rows like this:

```
|column A                              |

|normal data 1 (some data to remove 1) |
|normal data 2 (some  data to remove 2)|
|normal data 3 (some  data to remove 3)|
|normal data 4 (some  data to remove 4)|
|........                              |
```

and I want to update my rows to keep only normal data and delete data inside "()"
I'm wondering if there is a way to use regex inside my SQL update statement to delete all data after " ("

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use 2 **SUBSTRING_INDEX** like this if there also some data behind the ).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( YourFieldName , '(', 1),')',-1);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('normal data 1 (some data to remove 1)', '(', 1),')',-1);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('normal data 1 (some data to remove 1)', '(', 1),')',-1) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| normal data 1                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is `substring_index()`:

```
update t
    set col = substring_index(col, ' (', 1)
    where col like '% (%';
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume there is no '(' characters before the intended one?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use replace, substring and position functions to eliminate the data between ().

update tablename set col=replace(col,substr(col,position('(' in col),position(')' in col)-position('(' in col)),' ');

then it will update all the data between () inclunding braces.